# Java Quarkus how can I pass @ConfigProperty to an constructor?

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus, inject

I have the following class:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppScopeTest {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "my-config-prop")
    String test;
    
    private TestClass testclass;

    @Inject
    public AppScopeTest () {
        this.testClass= new TestClass (test);
    }
}
```

I have a few classes that want a new instance of `TestClass` created once that class is created. example is shown above. But if I do it this way the string Test is always null inside the class `TestClass`.

So my questions is how can I read a config property create a new instance of `TestClass` that takes that config property as an argument?

I don't want this to be a method call because when `AppScopeTest` is created I want an instance of `TestClass`

Comment: your code requires a `@PostConstruct` to be fully working but @iabughosh solution is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about doing it this way:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppScopeTest {

    private final String test;
    
    private TestClass testclass;

    @Inject
    public AppScopeTest (@ConfigProperty(name = "my-config-prop") String test) {
        this.testClass = new TestClass(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way @Inject on constructor is optional, you can remove it.